# Call code-behind to render view component from Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I have the following working code in a Razor page to render a ViewComponent:

```
...
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Start temperature tap water</td>
            <td class="text-end">@properties.StartTemperatureTapWater</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stop temperature tap water</td>
            <td class="text-end">@properties.StopTemperatureTapWater</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tap water operating hours</td>
            <td class="text-end"> @properties.TapWaterOperatingHours</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
@{
    var subCapability = Capabilities.FindCapability(capabilities, "TapWater.Temperatures");
    @await Component.InvokeAsync((string)subCapability.ClassName, new { deviceType = deviceType, capability = subCapability, level = 1 })
}
```

It would be nice if I could replace the two lines of code with a single function call to a code-behind function in my view, but I'm not sure how to replace the Component.InvokeAsync with my own function.

I use this to render nested ViewComponents like this:

[image]

The red rectangles shows each ViewComponent.

Comment: `"It would be nice if I could replace the two lines of code with a single function call to a code-behind function in my view"` Then what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Cleaner code in my Razor page.